# Docusign document did not appear in the order expected

Tags: docusignapi

I have an envelope with 6 documents. The sequence is: Canyonlands-ViewOnly.docx is 1, EightDocument.docx is 2, FifthDocument.docx is 3, FirstDocument.docx is 4, screenshots.docx is 5 and
Obama-ViewOnly.docx is 6. Here is the envelope definition

```
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "61323293-7f78-4e2b-a296-0c084db16f19"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "documents": [],
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Lori",
                "email": "kathylori@xxx.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "accessCode": "12345",
                "customFields": [],
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "note": "",
                "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",

              }
            ],
            "certifiedDeliveries": []
          },
          "customFields": {
            "textCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "EnvelopeInfo",
                "value": "my data"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "4",
        "name": "C:\\Temp\\Docusign\\Package\\Canyonlands-ViewOnly.docx",
        "fileExtension": ".docx",
        "order": "1",
        "documentFields": [
          {
            "name": "DMSID",
            "value": "1"
          }
        ],
        "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
      }
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "2",
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "3",
          "documents": [
            {
              "documentId": "5",
              "name": "C:\\Temp\\Docusign\\Package\\EightDocument.docx",
              "fileExtension": ".docx",
              "order": "2",
              "documentFields": [
                {
                  "name": "DMSID",
                  "value": "2"
                }
              ],
              "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
            },
            {
              "documentId": "6",
              "name": "C:\\Temp\\Docusign\\Package\\FifthDocument.docx",
              "fileExtension": ".docx",
              "order": "3",
              "documentFields": [
                {
                  "name": "DMSID",
                  "value": "3"
                }
              ],
              "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
            },
            {
              "documentId": "7",
              "name": "C:\\Temp\\Docusign\\Package\\FirstDocument.docx",
              "fileExtension": ".docx",
              "order": "4",
              "documentFields": [
                {
                  "name": "DMSID",
                  "value": "4"
                }
              ],
              "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
            },
            {
              "documentId": "9",
              "name": "C:\\Temp\\Docusign\\Package\\Obama-ViewOnly.docx",
              "fileExtension": ".docx",
              "order": "6",
              "documentFields": [
                {
                  "name": "DMSID",
                  "value": "6"
                }
              ],
              "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
            }
          ],
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Lori",
                "email": "kathylori@hotmail.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "accessCode": "12345",
                "customFields": [],
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "note": "",
                "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",

              }
            ],
            "certifiedDeliveries": []
          },
          "customFields": {
            "textCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "EnvelopeInfo",
                "value": "my data"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "2",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "templateId": "f0f1832a-9595-40ef-b40d-c5f384f299e3"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "3",
          "documents": [],
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Lori",
                "email": "kathylori@xxx.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "accessCode": "12345",
                "customFields": [],
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "note": "",
                "roleName": "Customer_SellerName",

              }
            ],
            "certifiedDeliveries": []
          },
          "customFields": {
            "textCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "EnvelopeInfo",
                "value": "my data"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "10837977",
        "name": "C:\\Temp\\Docusign\\Package\\screenshots.docx",
        "fileExtension": ".docx",
        "order": "5",
        "documentFields": [
          {
            "name": "DMSID",
            "value": "5"
          }
        ],
        "documentBase64": "[Document:Base64Array]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Here is the subject"
}
```

The last two documents have appeared out of order. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [listEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/list/) to retrieve the exact document ID's in the envelope

Once you have the documentID's use the [putEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/updateList/) api
to update the order of the documents.

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
     "documentId": "4567899",
     "order": "1",
    },
    {
     "documentId": "3245678",
     "order": "2",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So, would I have to put the envelope in a draft state, get its guid, then call listEnvelopeDocuments and then putEnvelopeDocuments? Will this work with composite templates?

Comment: Yes it would be better if the envelope is in Draft state. If the envelope is Sent, you can always correct it, but that would send multiple notifications to the recipients. It will work if the envelope was created from a composite template.

Comment: I guess the other thing I could do is to fix the ordering before sending it, which would be a bit of work figuring out which docs belong to which composite template and redoing the order.